# dataTaskWithURL crash unit testing in VIPER with swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, unit-testing, nsurlsession, swift-protocols

I'm Following [this tutorial](http://masilotti.com/testing-nsurlsession-input/) and trying to unit test my web services. The tutorial is in swift 2 and I've written it into swift 4.
I've done everything okay but the app is crashing, wether I'm unit-testing or running the app and I can't figure why. Can anyone help?

the crash line of code is:

```
extension URLSession : URLSessionProtocol{
    func dataTaskWithURL(url: NSURL, completionHandler: (Data?, URLResponse?, Error?) -> Void) -> URLSessionDataTaskProtocol {

        return dataTaskWithURL(url: url, completionHandler: completionHandler) //app crash

    }
}
```

Here is the full code of my webService:

```
import Foundation

protocol URLSessionProtocol {
    typealias DataTaskResult = (Data?, URLResponse?, Error?) -> Void

    func dataTaskWithURL(url: NSURL, completionHandler: DataTaskResult)
        -> URLSessionDataTaskProtocol
}
protocol URLSessionDataTaskProtocol {
    func resume()
}

class UserListRemoteDataManager:UserListRemoteDataManagerInputProtocol {

    var remoteRequestHandler: UserListRemoteDataManagerOutputProtocol?

    private let session : URLSessionProtocol

    init(session : URLSessionProtocol) {
        self.session = session
    }

    func retrieveUsers() {
        if let url = NSURL(string: Endpoints.Users.fetch.url){
            session.dataTaskWithURL(url: url, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in
                if error != nil {
                    print(error as Any)
                }
                if error == nil && data != nil {
                    do{
                        let users = try JSONDecoder().decode(UserModel.self, from: data!)
                        self.remoteRequestHandler?.onUsersRetrieved(users.users)
                    }catch let error as NSError {
                        print(error)
                        self.remoteRequestHandler?.onError()
                    }
                }
            }).resume()
        }
    }
}
extension URLSession : URLSessionProtocol{
    func dataTaskWithURL(url: NSURL, completionHandler: (Data?, URLResponse?, Error?) -> Void) -> URLSessionDataTaskProtocol {

        return dataTaskWithURL(url: url, completionHandler: completionHandler) //app crash

    }
}
extension URLSessionDataTask : URLSessionDataTaskProtocol{

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the tutorial you're following explains, the point of the `URLSessionProtocol` is to copy the function signature of the existing `URLSession` methods you want to test. However, you incorrectly updated the Swift 2 code from the tutorial, hence breaking this assumption. This caused the issue of `URLSession` not automatically conforming to `URLSessionProtocol`, hence you tried actually implementing the required protocol method, but instead of actually implementing it, the protocol just tries to recursively call itself, resulting in infinite recursion.

You need to change the required function of `URLSessionProtocol` to exactly match the `dataTask(with: <#T##URL#>, completionHandler: <#T##(Data?, URLResponse?, Error?) -> Void#>)` method of `URLSession`.

```
protocol URLSessionProtocol {
    typealias DataTaskResult = (Data?, URLResponse?, Error?) -> Void

    func dataTask(with: URL, completionHandler: DataTaskResult) -> URLSessionDataTask
}
```

Then you simply need to declare protocol conformance, but don’t actually need to implement the required method, since it’s already implemented by `URLSession`:

```
 extension URLSession: URLSessionProtocol {}
```